# Elasticsearch Custom Score Computation

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I  need to specify the  weights  for each field in  the  elasticsearch , for example

```
 {
    "firstname": 5,
    "lastname": 5,
    "email": 2
}
```

and  If I build a elastic query as follows ,

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "firstname": "jan"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "lastname": "skeet"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "emailid": "skeet@cco.in"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The document which  match the  firstname ,  lastname  and  emailId should have  a score of  12.
The document which matches only the firstname  should have  a  score of 5 and  vice versa for the  lastname and  emailid. 
The formula to be used is ,
  ***_score = (firstname weight+ lastname weight + emailid weight)***

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the perfect example for a [function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html), have you tried it out?

Comment: @Val  I have  tried  function score query  and what is  found  is the summation score  calculated  from  my custom weights is  getting  multiplied   by Lucene's Practical Scoring  function .  How  can override my  score  completely with Lucene's Score

Comment: Show your query please

Comment: @Val This is the  query .  How  will i specify weight here  for the field firstname {
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "firstname": "Athavan"
        }
      },
      "score_mode": "max",
      "script_score": {
        "script": "1 * 'doc[firstname].value'"
      }
    }
  }
}  .This returns an error since  'firstname'  field is not a numeric field